# How to add custom prefix before category base for category page URL?

Tags: categories, permalinks, slug

Is it possible to add a **custom prefix** right before the **category base** of the category page URL(s)?

For example, in the Category Page URL: `sample.com/category/top-10`, **category base** is `category`, and **term** is `top-10`

I want to add a custom prefix, so that the URL will be like this: `sample.com/my-custom-prefix/category/top-10`.

I've read the `add_rewrite_rule()` but I don't really get how to apply it to this approach. Is there any documentation that you could point me out, or any existing similar question here?

Comment: have you tried changing the category base from `category` to `prefix/category` then resaving permalinks? I don't believe code changes or developer know how are necessary for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done from WordPress `settings`.

Go to the admin panel of your WordPress site (also known as the Dashboard), and from the left menu, go to `Settings ⟹ Permalinks`:

[image: WordPress permalink settings]

From there, you'll see the `Category base` input field.

Use the prefix you want in this input field, e.g. `my-custom-prefix/category` and then <kbd>Save Changes</kbd>.

If this is a new site, then this should be enough, no need to do any code change. After this change, your category Page URL `sample.com/category/top-10` will become `sample.com/my-custom-prefix/category/top-10`.

If this is an old site with old category links, then in addition to the above step, it's better to redirect the older category links using either a redirect plugin or `.htaccess`.

Following are a couple of links with some additional details about categories that may be helpful to you:

1. https://wordpress.org/support/article/posts-categories-screen/
2. https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/categories-and-tags/categories/